# sqlalchemy trigger automatic insert after delete on different table

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with python, wondering if it is possible to automatically insert a record into table `Deleted Users` when a record has been deleted from table `Users`.

I know that using a foreign key, I can use the on_delete attribute to delete records from connected tables but I need to insert record.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume both tables have the same schema (2 columns; `user_id` and `username`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Triggers or a "deleted" column might be the most reliable way to do this, but if you'd like to do it using SQLAlchemy, the event API could be the way to go.

```py
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.sql import dml, select

def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for instance in session.deleted:
        if isinstance(instance, User):
            # insert into the deleted user table

def before_execute(conn, clauseelement, multiparams, params):
    if isinstance(clauseelement, dml.Delete):
       if clauseelement.table.name == "user":
           query = select([clauseelement.table])
           if clauseelement._whereclause is not None:
               query = query.where(clauseelement._whereclause)
           for row in conn.execute(query):
               # insert into the deleted user table

event.listen(session, "before_flush", before_flush)
event.listen(engine, "before_execute", before_execute)
```

The `before_flush` function would capture ORM deletes while the `before_execute` captures generic queries that delete from the user table.

Comment: +1 for a `deleted` bool column if you are only going to be transferring the same data to another table with the same schema.

Comment: Having a `deleted` column makes querying more challenging, though. A separate history table does not interfere with day to day queries.

Comment: I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and I want to insert data into another table when insert is performed on one table how can I do it using this?